# FreeTDS: Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, freetds, django-pyodbc, tdsodbc

I'm trying to connect to a MSSQL 2005 server using FreeTDS.

But I'm getting the "Login failed for user" error. There is a section on it in the [FreeTDS manual](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm#TSQL) trouble shooting section. But it does not mention any possible errors related to it. Can it be an issue with my tsql connection string? Or is it something misconfigured on the MSSQL side?

I am able to connect to the SQL Server Management using the same credentials.

This is what I am using and the output (I've removed the ipnumber and username):

```
$ TDSVER=4.2 tsql -H <ipnumber> -p 1433 -U <username>
Password:
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from PS136 Line 1:
        "Login failed for user '<username>'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
        Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

And my compile time settings:

```
$ tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed FreeTDS like so:

```
 $sudo apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin tdsodbc
```

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong, the package they are referring to must be `tdsodbc` found here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/tdsodbc

Comment: Thanks. But I still have the same issue. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I had been given the wrong port number. I also needed to specify the `instance` in the freetds config file.

Comment: Well the port had to do with that specific setup. Ask the system admin for the one that pertains to you.

Comment: were you not able to bypass the config file then?

Comment: @brad: Not sure what you mean by that. This was years ago and I haven't worked with MSSQL since, thank God.

Answer (score 0):

I also use freetds to connect to SQL Server 2012.

I have this section in my freetds.conf file

```
[mycomp]
        host = some.ipnumber.or.hostname
        port = 1433
        client charset = UTF-8
        tds version = 8.0
```

Then I connect with sqsh (isql replacement, also in the ubuntu repos)

```
 sqsh -I /etc/freetds/freetds.conf -Smycomp  -Uknb -Psecrit
```

This is my tsql -C output

```
○ → tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

Comment: But using the command I posted above should bypass the settings file, if I am not mistaken. So it should not be a config file issue.

Comment: Yes I did try that as well.

Comment: i've added my tsql -C output. Single difference is 'kerberos' param. Didn't configure that actively myself, don't know how it got into the compile time settings.